# Finding rows in a dataframe with a matching value in column and performing chi squared test

Tags: r, subset

I have a dataframe in R with columns named 'lim' 'eye_colour' 'ref' and 'alt'.

I want to subset the dataframe to find rows with matching values for 'lim', and then perform a chi squared test to see whether there is any difference between 'ref' and 'alt' for the two options for 'eye_colour'

I'm struggling to subset the dataframe based on the matching values.

There are about 60 unique values for 'lim' so I don't want to subset by specifying df[df$lim == "frog", ] as I'm hoping to find a way to automate this.

I also want to run this in a loop so that the code runs for each of the unique lim values

The following code works:

```
    df_lim_frog <- df[df$lim == "frog", ]
    chisq_result_frog <- chisq.test(df_lim_frog[, c("ref", "alt")])
```

But I don't want to rewrite and run the code 60 times - is there a way to automate it

I've tried this, but I got back dataframes that had been incorrectly subsetted - not matching lim values, it seemed pretty random.

```
     duplicates <- duplicated(df$lim) | duplicated(df$lim, fromLast = TRUE)

     subsets <- split(df, df$lim[duplicates])
```

Comment: Pleas post some reprodicible data, using, for example, `dput(YOURDATA)` or `dput(head(YOURDATA))`